# OnNavigationItemSelectedListener starting activity instead of replacing fragment

Tags: android, navigationbar, bottomnavigationview, onitemselectedlistener

I am new to programming and I am creating an app with bottomNavigationView. In my Welcome activity I have my OnItemSelectedListener. But when I run the app in an android device and select an option it doesn't replace the fragment instead starts the Welcome Activity again and again.

This is the Welcome activity which keeps starting no matter what item I select from the BottonNavigationView.

```
public class Welcome extends AppCompatActivity {
private Context mContext = Welcome.this;

private static final String TAG = "Welcome";
BottomNavigationViewEx bottomNav;
private List<ListItems> listItems;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_welcome);
    Log.d(TAG, "onCreate: starting");
    setupBottomNavigationView();
    Toast.makeText(this, "Starting", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

    enableNavigation();

    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, homeFragment).commit();

}

private void setupBottomNavigationView(){
    Log.d(TAG, "setupBottomNavigationView: setting bottomnavigationview");
    bottomNav = findViewById(R.id.nav_bottom);
    BottomNavigationViewHelper.setUpNavigationView(bottomNav);
}


private void enableNavigation(){
    bottomNav.setOnNavigationItemSelectedListener(new BottomNavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(@NonNull MenuItem item) {
            switch(item.getItemId()){
                case R.id.btnHome:
                    bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.btnHome);
                    HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, homeFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.btnChats:
                    bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.btnChats);
                    ChatsFragment chatsFragment = new ChatsFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager1 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager1.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, chatsFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.btnPost:
                    bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.btnPost);
                    PostsFragment postsFragment = new PostsFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager2 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager2.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, postsFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.btnFavourites:
                    bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.btnFavourites);
                    FavouritesFragment favouritesFragment = new FavouritesFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager3 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager3.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, favouritesFragment).commit();
                    break;
                case R.id.btnProfile:
                    bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.btnProfile);
                    ProfileFragment profileFragment = new ProfileFragment();
                    android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager4 = getSupportFragmentManager();
                    manager4.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, profileFragment).commit();
                    break;
            }
            return false;
        }
    });

}
}
```

This is the layout_welcome file

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout

xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
tools:context="com.matt.mustjob.Home.Welcome">

<android.support.v4.view.ViewPager
    android:id="@+id/container"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_marginBottom="50dp"/>

<com.ittianyu.bottomnavigationviewex.BottomNavigationViewEx
    android:id="@+id/nav_bottom"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_gravity="bottom"
    android:background="#431C60"
    app:menu="@menu/menu"
    app:itemIconTint="#fff"
    app:itemTextColor="#FFF"/>

</android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A few things you need to change:

1) Don't use a `ViewPager` as your `Fragment` container, there's a way to use `Fragments` with a `ViewPager` and manage it in the `Adapter`. Do a Google search for "*viewpager with fragments example in android*" to learn how to work with it. If you don't need a `ViewPager` functionality, you can use a `FrameLayout` as the container.

2) You don't need to save the `Context` in an `Activity`, you can always use `getApplicationContext()`, `getBaseContext()` or simply `this` (or `YourActivity.this` depending on the scope)

3) No need to call `getSupportFragmentManager();` every time. You can call it once and assign the reference to a member in the `Activity`:

```
private FragmentManager manager;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    ...
    manager = getSupportFragmentManager()
}

// Somewhere else:
manager.beginTransaction()...
```

4) You need to return `true;` after you handle the `onNavigationItemSelected` event, so instead of calling `break;` after each choice, do like this:

```
...
case R.id.btnHome:
  bottomNav.setSelectedItemId(R.id.btnHome);
  HomeFragment homeFragment = new HomeFragment();
  android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager manager = getSupportFragmentManager();
  manager.beginTransaction().replace(R.id.container, homeFragment).commit();
  return true; // This thing here
...
```

Comment: This way activity is not starting again and again but it is not yet replacing fragment.

Comment: Go through the Android documentation to know how to start an activity: https://developer.android.com/training/basics/firstapp/starting-activity

Answer (score 0):

Besides of @Hed Shafran's answer, try this out:

Check your logcat. Some device might not showing the ANR dialog when the apps crashes. The *starts the Welcome Activity again and again* case might just because of the apps has stopped working since there's an error.